# Reorder a linq expression after using Take()

Tags: vb.net, linq, visual-studio-2015

I have 2 datasets that I wrote linq to extract wanted results from. I ordered a dataset via the sql so I could cull those results using linq. I used Take() to get the rows I needed but now I need to reorder them so I can emit them as a spreadsheet using EPPlus. I'm using VS2015 vb.net.

Here is the code:

```
Dim linqTemp = (From t1 In dsTempResults.Tables(0).AsEnumerable Group Join
                 t2 In _myDtPalletGun.AsEnumerable On t1.Field(Of String)("item_no") Equals t2.Field(Of String)("Item_No")
                        Into dataGroup = Group From row In dataGroup.DefaultIfEmpty Where row IsNot Nothing
                        Select t1).Distinct().Take(Convert.ToInt16(Me.txtNumberToReturn.Text))
```

Succinctly, I'd like to know how to reorder the results of a linq queries returned records.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this at the end of your query;

```
.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.MyOrderProperty).ToList();
```

The first ToList() evaluates the database query, the orderby orders the objects that are now in memory.

(Aside; this code `dsTempResults.Tables(0).AsEnumerable` looks like it might be bringing back *everything* in Tables(0) before doing the join. Watch out that it isn't bringing back too much data.)

Comment: I tried your line. I'm probably not smart enough to get it to work. I tried it and googled "OrderBy" I don't get it. But.. I was able to lay a little cheat. I just did another linq based on previous linq and it worked. I added this line:  Dim linqSort = (From l1 In linqTemp Select l1 Order By l1.Field(Of String)("item_no"))

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I made it work. I just did another linq based on previous linq and it worked. I added this line:

```
Dim linqSort = (From l1 In linqTemp Select l1 Order By l1.Field(Of String)("item_no"))
```